# Add database default value to dropdown list using jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, laravel

I'm working with CRUD operation using jQuery AJAX and bootstrap modal in laravel. But the problem is when I want to edit something. I can't populate my dropdown list after an AJAX success request. How can I set database default value in my edit modal Dropdown List?

My Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.acedit').click(function() {
    $('#form')[0].reset();
    $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
      url: "{{route('academic.edit')}}",
      method: 'post',
      data: {
        id: id,
        '_token': "{{csrf_token()}}"
      },
      success: function(data) {
        //$('#mycontrolId').selectmenu('refresh').val(myvalue).attr("selected", "selected");
        $('.degree').val(data.degree).attr('selected', true);
        $('.divison').val(data.division);
        $('.year').val(data.year);
        console.log(data); //{id: 2, user_id: 5, degree: "ssc", division: "First", year: "2009", …}
      }
    });
  });
});
```

My Controller Method:

```
public function acadedit(Request $request){
    $id=$request->id;
    $info=Academic::find($id);
    return $info;
}
```

My edit modal Dropdown list:

```
<select class="form-control degree">
    <option value="">-Select Degree-</option>
    <option value="SSC">SSC</option>
    <option value="HSC">HSC</option>
    <option value="BBA">BBA</option>
    <option value="MBA">MBA</option>
</select>
```

Comment: '@Bugfixer ' i have edited and add the console.log(data) the line.

Comment: wat does `console.log(data);` return... can you check in your browser console..!

Comment: No i want the output of console.log. remove everything from success and write only console.log(data). Then check your browser console. you will see output. paste that result here

Comment: try using `.attr("selected","selected");`  or `.prop('selected', true)`.

Comment: **{id: 2, user_id: 5, degree: "ssc", division: "First", year: "2009", …}**, Here is my console result. I want to set degree value in my edit modal.

Comment: Nothing Changed. @ruhul

Comment: Check for case! You may want to upcase degree  value in ajax success callback `$('.degree').val(data.degree.toUpperCase())`

Comment: ssc is small letter and option value is capital

Comment: ok, try using `data.degree.toUpperCase()` :P

Comment: @linktoahref it's working. thank you and thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `selected` attribute on the `<select>` element, it's only for the `<option>`s. However, you don't really need it, because setting the value of the `<select>` element is enough to change the selection. But you need to match the value exactly with the proper letter casing, so all capital letters in your case.

Change this:

```
$('.degree').val(data.degree).attr('selected',true);
```

To:

```
$('.degree').val(data.degree.toUpperCase());
```

If you really prefer to do it with the attribute on the `<option>` instead of the `value` of the `<select>`, then you need to add the `<option>` to the jQuery selector like this:

```
$('.degree option[value=' + data.degree.toUpperCase() + ']').attr('selected', true);
```

Demo:

```js
$('.degree option[value=SSC]').attr('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control degree">
  <option value="">-Select Degree-</option>
  <option value="SSC">SSC</option>
  <option value="HSC">HSC</option>
  <option value="BBA">BBA</option>
  <option value="MBA">MBA</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to use response data from your Controller by Ajax, then it better to return it in Json format:
   Use `return response()->json($info);` instead of `return $info;`
2. As I can see from your console.log output you receive `degree: "ssc"`, whereas
   your select option is `SSC`, so you need to uppercase the data before use it: `$('.degree').val(data.degree.toUpperCase());` or to downcase values of select options: `<option value="ss">SSC</option>`.